# Importing Contacts of different websites into our database

Tags: wordpress, facebook, linkedin-api, gmail-api, yahoo-api

My project requires that I should let the user using my website to either import his/her contacts from gmail,yahoo, hotmail,facebook,linkedin so that I can save them their contacts email id in our database and send them invitation email to join our website or if importing from all these websites is not possible then directly using some api to directly send invitations via these websites.

I will really appreciate any sort of help as I am new to wordpress and hence not aware about lot of plugins and searched the internet a lot but didn’t find anything constructive. I have visited my yahoo mail id and can see I can import my contacts from facebook,gmail,outlook and other yahoo accounts so that means there is 100% some API which yahoo guys are using.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very, very broad, but here are the APIs you might want to look into:

[Google Contacts API Version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) Look under **Retrieving all contacts**.

[Yahoo Contacts API](https://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/)

[Hotmail](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/ca05e45d-d0cd-4c5c-85c8-55ee1f51fd8f/how-to-retrieve-a-userc-contacts-emails?forum=messengerconnect) doesn't seem to have a proper way of getting the contacts.

[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/friendlist)

[LinkedIn](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?apig_cc=1) Check out the example "Get My Connections".

Good luck!